# Почему JavaScript такой какой он есть сейчас?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Глядя на те языки, которые были доступны на момент создания JavaScript, я задаюсь вопросом: Почему JavaScript пошел именно этим путем и стал таким, каким он является сейчас?

Большое кол-во неинтуитивно понятных конструкций и тонкостей, которые вытекают из динамической типизации.

Например, ключевые слова `static`, `const`, `class` добавили в язык совсем недавно, но на момент создания языка они уже имелись в других языках.

Если бы JavaScript имел бы статическую типизацию, то неужели бы он не был приманим в браузерах как сейчас?

Изначально, если верить Wiki, ставилась цель сделать JavaScript понятным для всех, но разве, то что есть сейчас справляется с изначальной целью?

Comment: Насколько мне известно из истории JavaScript, один авантюрист предложил в короткие сроки сделать скриптовый язык для браузеров. Естественно, что такая поделка не могла отличаться качеством, так как задача авантюриста состояла в том, чтобы срубить побольше бабла с фирмы, впарив любое фуфло, лишь бы оно что-то делало.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow Отсюда и миллион фреймворков вытекает

Answer (score 4):

Была такая статья «The World’s Most Misunderstood Programming Language Has Become the World’s Most Popular Programming Language» «Самый неправильно понятый язык программирования в мире стал самым популярным в мире языком программирования» [Статья](http://javascript.crockford.com/popular.html)

Если вкратце, популярность к языку пришла случайно в связи с ростом популярности браузеров. Ну а потом понеслось: V8, Node, Phonegap.

Answer (score 2):

Ну вообще JS вышел таким потому что приоритетом было как можно наискорейшее его выход в свет. Некоторое время язык особо и не развивался, заложенных изначально возможностей хватало чтобы писать скрипты. Но когда ПО начало переезжать в браузеры, потребовалось больше возможностей. Пришлось внедрять новые возможности, однако не исправили старые проблемы. Как мне думается из-за огромного количества проблем разрабатывается огромное количество библиотек и фреймворков, что уже стало своеобразным мемом